# incoing email error delivered to delivered to mydomain.localdomain

Tags: email, postfix

I am transferring my mail server to a new VPS and it has not been as easy his time. I have changed all the IPs and set Reverse DNS on the new VPS.

I have set the hostname in /etc/postfix/main.cf and made other necessary modifications.

I can send an email to my gmail address but when I send a reply I get error an message saying domain 'mydomain.localdomai' couldn’t be found. I cannot find anywhere in any config files where 'mydomain.localdomain' is set.

Anyone got any idea what the issue is?

Thanks!

Comment: to clarify: are you saying the message is exactly `mydomain.localdomain`, that's not just a placeholder for the purposes of the question?

Comment: did you check `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: Debian-derived systems provision their postfix config with a pointer to `/etc/mailname` instead of literally spelling the host name, so you may have missed reviewing that when you adapted the main.cf file.

Comment: 'mydomain.localdomain' is exactly what is says

Comment: /etc/hosts has localhost and the FQD and auto generated at boot

Comment: /etc/mailname has the FQD

Comment: It seems my hosting provider was adding '.localdomain' onto the end of the hostname. I changed the hostname in the VPS control panel and sure enough the VPS hostname had '.localdomain' tacked on the end. I removed this, rebooted and the email server works.